# Weird JSON parsing behavior in js, "Unexpected token :"

Tags: javascript, json

As demonstrated in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aAQa3/1/), if you have a JS file and you create a JSON object without using it, it behaves differently depending on whether the keys(members) are wrapped in quotes or not.

valid code:`{ a: 1};`
invalid code: `{ "a": 1 };`

What you will get is an error message (in Chrome, different for FF/IE, but still fails on syntax)

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

but if you use the object in some way, for example: `alert({ "a": 1 });` everything is OK again.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The statement:

```
{ a: 1 };
```

is **not** an object literal. It's a block statement with one labeled expression in it. It's valid.

This:

```
{ "a": 1 };
```

is a syntax error because it's just not parseable. The quoted "a" starts an expression statement inside the block, but then the next token after the string is a colon, and there's no expression form that looks like an expression followed by a colon.

Now:

```
var x = { "a": 1 };
```

works because the "{" is not interpreted as the start of a block statement.  That statement starts with `var`, so it's a variable declaration. Within the expression on the right side of the "=" token, the only thing that a "{" can mean is the start of an object literal. Similarly, note that:

```
({ "a": 1 });
```

is OK because the opening parenthesis makes the parser expect a nested subexpression, so again the "{" unambiguously means that it's the start of an object literal.

Comment: but assigning it to a var makes it an object literal?

Comment: Yes, because there is no ambiguity.

Comment: i think it's the labeled statement i didn't see coming. never even saw JS code with use of labels, though i vaguely remembered it's supported

Comment: Yes it's a pretty rarely-used feature of the language. Possibly it's most commonly used by accident when people put "javascript:" at the beginning of "onfoo" attribute values :-)

Comment: Pointy, what are you to do, when your serializer, serializes your data into the incorrect format of `{ "a": 1 }`?

Comment: Well that's only incorrect if you try to let JavaScript parse it as a statement. It's perfectly good JSON.

Answer (score 3):

I just realized than when loading the JSON via `require` and the filename does not end on `.json` i get this error. Renaming the file to `bla.json` and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This error can popup when doing a jQuery AJAX call using `jsonp` when `jsonp` is not necessary. Try switching your data type on your AJAX call if this is the case to normal `json`

```
$.ajax({
     dataType: 'json', // try using json rather than json p
     ...
});
```