# Why does var o = {"a" : "b"}; executes and does what I expect, while eval('{"a": "b"}') fails?

Tags: javascript

When I was fixing a bug in old code using evals, I realized something really weird about expression evaluation.

If you open a JavaScript console and type

```
eval ('{"a": "b"}')
```

or

```
{"a": "b"}
```

You get

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

But if you type

```
var o = {"a": "b"};
```

The statement executes with the expectable result.

And also if you type

```
(function() {return {"a": "b"};})()
```

You get:

```
Object {a: "b"}
```

Also, if you type `{a: "b"}`, you get "b". I don't understand that at all.

I was used to think that `var o = {"a": "b"};` meaned "evaluate the expression `{"a": "b"}` and assign the result to `o`.

But apparently it's more complicated than that. I try to find the explanation on that point in the language specification, but I don't think I use the right wording to search.

Can anybody provide a clue about why I can return or assign the value of something that is not a valid evaluable expression by itself to a variable ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird JSON parsing behavior in js, "Unexpected token :"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080551/weird-json-parsing-behavior-in-js-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, writing `var o = {"a":"b"}` means "create an object with one member named `a` whose value is `b`, and assign this object as the value of the local variable `o`".

Brackets have nothing to do with evaluating expressions, they're used in JavaScript for Object notation:

```
var a = {
   foo:1,
   baz:2
}

console.log(a.foo);
console.log(a.baz);
```

This will output:

```
1
2
```

JS object notation.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that curly braces are used for two purposes in Javascript: they surround object literals, and they also surround code blocks.

The console and `eval` are interpreting the braces as starting a code block, but you're typing an object literal instead. This is causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
eval('({"a":"b"})'); // mind the parens
```

The reasoning why they are needed is the same as described in the answers of: [What do parentheses surrounding a JavaScript object/function/class declaration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q440739/)

Though you probably want to use proper JSON parsing: [`JSON.parse(str)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: Sure but I was actually investigating a very old code that's already in production. Tx for the advice lol

Comment: A more sane solution to `eval(str)` is `Function('return (' + str + ')')()`. At least the scoping is well defined and it will work in a `use strikt` context. But you would only have to use that, if you do not transmit proper JSON, but JavaScript. Otherwise you might consider updating the production code nevertheless. ;)