# What bases does Reference have?

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm wondering which bases Reference has in different situations.
For example: undefined, Object, Boolean, String, Number, Environment Record.

I will assume that the base for declaring the variable "a" will be the Environment Record. And the structure of Reference "a" will look like this:

```
/// Definition variable in javascript code
var a;
/// Reference structure in engine
Reference = {
    Base: Environment Record, /// It's one of other cases
    ReferencedName: "a", 
    StrictReference: false
}
```

I'm not saying that what I wrote correctly, I just want to know how the structures look in other types.

Comment: Uh, yes, exactly those that you mentioned: "*[The base value is either undefined, an Object, a Boolean, a String, a Number, or an environment record](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7).*"

Comment: @Bergi I know, I need examples of the pseudocode that I showed (for each **base** value).

Comment: Try `a` (with no variable of that name declared anywhere), `{}.a`, `true.a`, `"".a`, `0..a`, and `a` (with that variable existing in scope).

Comment: @Bergi what does it mean **try**? I hope to see detail explanation.

Comment: Try to evaluate those expressions I gave you using the algorithm detailed in the spec (since that's what you're interested in) and arrive at the results that you asked for. There is no further explanation beyond what is given in the spec. If you do not understand a particular detail, ask about it specifically.

Comment: @Bergi hmm ok. What is the difference between `obj.a` and `{}.a`. In first case what is will be base? And second case? obj - `var obj = {a:"something"};`

Comment: There's no difference about the *Reference* structure apart from its base being a different object. They're both property references. Of course [GetValue](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) will return a different thing when the property does not exist in the object, but the reference isn't concerned with that.

Comment: @Bergi I know it. But meaning of the my question int the next: 
View the reference base for different examples. P.S Do not avoid from my guiding questions

Comment: @Bergi can you explain me this part of note (ES5.1): `The only situation where such an actual property access that uses this internal method can have visible effect is when it invokes an accessor function.` What is it about, I do not understand! P.S I can ask it as a new question, if it need!

Comment: Not exactly sure either about that. I think it means that implementation can heavily optimise these accesses, they are pure and have no observable effects - except for getter properties. Notice that [ES6 removed this wording](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getvalue)…

Comment: @Bergi yeah i saw it in ES6. But `except for getter properties`. Can you give me example (code) for better understanding pls.

Comment: `{get a() { console.log("!"); return 1 }}.a`

Comment: @Bergi but i get an `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. Why?

Comment: @Bergi Your example is a literal object and this no longer fits into the concept of a primitive base! The [[Get]] method for the primitive base creates an object. That is, the example should be like `10.toString()` or `true.toString()` or `"hello".toUpperCase()`. Note for special version [[Get]] when base is a primitive, right?

Comment: You get the SyntaxError because of [the usual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10080551/1048572)

Comment: Oops, of course, it's about primitive bases. In that case, `Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "a", { get() { console.log("!"); } }); "".a`

Comment: @Bergi thx for warning about `{` I forgot about this behaviour

Comment: @Bergi It seems I understand what you mean by this ... If I understand you correctly then we use a special method (`Object.defineProperty`) to define an accessor (get / set) for a concrete property and a concrete primitive type. The visible effect is meant to what we notice as a result of the accessor's operation? Correctly?

Comment: @Bergi what means: `that implementation can heavily optimise these accesses,` **they are pure** `and have` **no observable effects**. Sorry what I did not ask it before: `except for getter properties`. Some things too hard to understand without additional explanation.

Comment: @Bergi why do you silent? What's up?

Comment: Not sure what additional explanation there is. And to be honest, it's just guesswork anyway, I don't know what the author thought about.

Comment: @Bergi I think you are right about this note, asserting! But I asked you about **they are pure** and **no observable effects** (yours words). And I also asked you if I was right about what you wrote. Sorry for this obsession.

Comment: I just meant [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)

Comment: @Bergi ok, and it too ([pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)) address to **no observable effects** (did you means it in value *side effects*?)

Comment: @Bergi Excuse me for such perseverance, I know that you do not owe me anything, but just you are the only one who even answers every question on ECMAScript. And I feel uncomfortable when there is some kind of understatement. I sometimes ask you to either agree or not, it's not difficult. Yes, I understand that you are busy, so I wait a considerable time. P.S Comments are not intended for such a large dialog as in this matter (I somehow called you in a chat room but you did not go).